# javascript form data append из другой функции

Tags: javascript

В аякс запросе, формируется formdata.

```
data = new FormData();
data.append('title', $('#aititle').val().trim());
data.append('message', $('#aitextarea').val().trim());
```

Вопрос, возможно ли добавить данные, из другой функции? Когда я сделал так:

```
data.append('image', formimgs());
```

И в функции создал new `Formdata()` и сделал `append`, вернув результат, то этими данными, заменилась основная `formdata`, в которую я делал `append`.

Comment: так не делайте `new FormData()` используйте уже существующую переменную

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych да, что-то я не предусмотрел, нужно было просто передать data, в функцию.